# How is the reattachment of a soul after it's been put in a Horcrux known?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

IIRC, there's only 2 people that have created a Horcrux. One is the inventor, and the other is Tom Riddle.

My question is 2 part:

1. Are there other instances of a Horcrux being created?
2. How was it discovered that remorse would repair the soul (AFAIK you can't see souls...)?

Bonus points if you know who felt remorse!

Comment: We only hear about to Horcrucifiers, but I’m sure there must have been more. If no one had performed the spell since Herpo the Foul, thousands of years ago, it would be quite impressive for the spell to still be so well-known and recorded in books on Dark Magic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet IT can't be well known, as Hermione even had a hard time finding it. She went through an entire library without ever finding a mention of it.

Comment: It’s obscure, yes, but consider that a) Slughorn (who teaches Potions, not DaDA) knows a fair bit about it without looking anything up, and b) Tom Riddle managed to find sufficient information about it _in the same library_ to actually perform the spell and create a Horcrux by the time he was the same age as Hermione. Given this, it must still have been reasonably well-documented in books available during the 20th century, which would be surprising if it had _never_ been attempted for over two thousand years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Are there any other instances of a Horcrux being created, besides Voldemort and Herpo the Foul?

Probably. None are mentioned explicitly. However, Tom Riddle got the information from a variety of books. Of these, at least one, *Secrets of the Darkest Art*, explained in detail how to create a Horcrux. It seems likely that the author of this book had actually created a Horcrux, and, given that its title was not in Greek, it was most likely not written by Herpo the Foul. Moreover, the general familiarity of various authors and individuals with Horcruxes suggests that they were not a one-off type of Dark Magic invented by Herpo and never used in the interim, but a method that had been used in recent centuries. However, there is no canonical confirmation that anyone but Herpo or Voldemort even created a Horcrux.

### How was it discovered that remorse could repair the soul?

Recall that it is not the creation of a Horcrux that splits the soul, but murder:

> “Well,” said Slughorn uncomfortably, “you must understand  that the
>   soul is supposed to remain intact and whole. Splitting it is an act of
>   violation, it is against nature.”
>
> “But how do you do it?”
>
> “By an act
>   of evil — the supreme act of evil. By committing murder. Killing rips
>   the soul apart. The wizard intent upon creating a Horcrux would use
>   the damage to his advantage: He would encase the torn portion —”

Dumbledore says the same:

> “If you don’t mind dying,” said Snape roughly, “why not let Draco do
>   it?”
>
> “That boy’s soul is not yet so damaged,” said Dumbledore. “I
>   would not have it ripped apart on my account.”

So even if very few Horcruxes have been created, many wizards (and Muggles) have committed murder, and thus ripped their souls apart. So there are plenty of test cases for rejoining souls.

Of course, wizards cannot see souls. But I assume that magic can sense the nature or state of a soul, somehow. That would seem the most logical explanation for how Herpo could discover the method of creating Horcruxes, which almost requires one to know the state of a soul. One could certainly see a skillful wizard assessing their soul before and after murder, and before and after remorse, and noting that it has rejoined.

Comment: Nice answer, Photon man! +1